# Angular load times troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, angular

All,

A company I'm working with outsourced some development to a third-party company.  The developers at this third-party company are "using" Ng 7 (using in quotes, because much of the functionality is hand-written instead of using what's out of the box).

The app is VERY sluggish.

Inside the *root* component, I call a service's `init` method.  The init method creates a start time and then calls and observer on the `applicationRef.isStable` object.  When the application becomes stable, it returns to the `init` method that then gets the end time and calculates a delta between the end and start times.  This delta is then printed to the console.

The difference in time ranges anywhere from 60 second to 200+ seconds.

Obviously, the code has issues as it shouldn't take 3+ minutes for the application to become stable.

**Question:**
Is there a tool that can help me troubleshoot what's taking so long for the application to become stable?

Thanks.

Comment: that is truly absurd.  I'm not familiar with any tools but you should be able to track what needs to occur for the application to become stable by checking the references / what it's waiting for. Sounds like your company should be trashing this code though and getting their money back.

Comment: @bryan60 as it turns out, it appears the developer is using an observable for local caching then subscribing to it on all the pages.  I removed the call to the cache and, instead, calls the API on every page load.  the stable time went from 60-90-300+ secs down to 1-2 secs.

Comment: that's... interesting? caching generally improves performance on a client. must've been a "non-standard" cache implementation.

Comment: @bryan60 he wrote his own. :(

Comment: hopefully management at your company learned a valuable lesson about tech debt

Answer (score 0):

I would go with chrome's performance:

[image: F12 and then performance tag]

Check for guidance [on google's guide](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance)

Checking on the network tab could also help, to figure out if it's XHR requests that are causing the problem

[image: Network tab example]

Comment: it's not networking nor UI related.  All networking calls have been completed and the UI is rendered.  However, it still takes 3 minutes for the application to become stable.